# How to add columns dynamically to data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two datetime variables Start Date and End Date.Suppose Start Date is 01-Jan-2013 and End date is 01-Mar-2013.Then I have to add datagridview columns as Jan,Feb,Mar.
Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: how do u try?? I mean u should show some codes

Comment: What have you tried? What about a simple `dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column","Jan");`

Comment: Well you can use `grid1.Columns.Add` method to do it

Comment: Is your `datagridview` bound to some datasource ?

Comment: add column permanently or temporary ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string[] months = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);

while (true)
{
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add(months[startDate.Month - 1], months[startDate.Month - 1]);
   startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
   if (startDate > endDate)
       break;
}
```

Of course you should make proper validation checks in this code too.